# How to send e-mail with attachments using Camel SMTP component and Camel XML DSL route definitions?

Tags: java, spring, email, apache-camel

I have the following route definitions file:

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <setHeader headerName="from">
            <constant>user@mailserver.com</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="to">
            <constant>john.smith@acme.com</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="subject">
            <constant>Hello</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="contentType">
            <constant>text/plain;charset=UTF-8</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setBody>
            <constant>Test</constant>
        </setBody>
        <!-- <attachment id="attachment.zip" uri="resource:file:test.zip"/> -->
        <to uri="smtp://user@mailserver.com?password=secret"/>
    </route>
</routes>
```

It is possible to send e-mail with attachments using Java DSL:

```
Endpoint endpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint(
        "smtp://user@mailserver.com?password=secret");
Exchange exchange = endpoint.createExchange();
Message in = exchange.getIn();
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("from", "user@mailserver.com");
headers.put("to", "john.smith@acme.com");
headers.put("subject", "Hello");
headers.put("contentType", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
in.setHeaders(headers);
in.setBody("Test");
in.addAttachment("attachment.zip", new DataHandler(
        applicationContext.getResource("file:test.zip").getURL()));
Producer producer = endpoint.createProducer();
producer.start();
producer.process(exchange);
```

But I need to perform that using XML DSL only.
Is there any way to do that in Camel?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035278/how-to-send-file-as-mail-attachment-via-camel-spring-dsl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a way, but it requires additional `camel-script` component.

Replacing

```
<!-- <attachment id="attachment.zip" uri="resource:file:test.zip"/> -->
```

with

```
<filter>
    <groovy>request.addAttachment("attachment.zip",
            new javax.activation.DataHandler(
            new javax.activation.FileDataSource("test.zip")))
    </groovy>
    <to uri="mock:dummy"/>
</filter>
```

does the job.

P.S.: Thanks to matt helliwell for pointing me to a similar question.

Comment: I am gonna send a file as an attachment to an email as soon as the file is being created in a directory.

Is it possible to change the route to do so?

I tried to change "from" tag like this <from uri="file://camel/input"/> and also replace "test.zip" with ${header.CamelFileName} but it was not a successful try.

Could you help please?